# VBA - recursive combination listing based on Excel columns

Tags: vba, excel, combinatorics

I have rewritten a recursive procedure to list combinations of values in Excel columns in a way, that instead of one cell string output, there is an array output to Excel range (one value per cell, one combination per row). It lists up to 1 000 000 combinations and executes in 45 seconds / 1 000 000 combinations on my PC. Are any improvements which would let me decrease execution time possible?

```
   Sub ListCombinations()

    Dim arr As Variant, outCnt As Long, vOut() As Variant
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim tim As Double: tim = Timer

    arr = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("assignment optimization").Range("b2:j12")
    ReDim vOut(1000000, UBound(arr, 2))
    outCnt = 1
    Arrangements arr, vbNullString, LBound(arr, 2), outCnt, vOut

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("assignment optimization")
        With Range(.Cells(1, 12), .Cells(outCnt, 11 + UBound(vOut, 2)))
            lastRow = .Columns.Find(what:="*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
            .Columns.ClearContents
            .Value = vOut
        End With
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Debug.Print Timer - tim

End Sub

Sub Arrangements(ByRef arr, ByVal s As String, ByVal lInd As Long, ByRef outCnt As Long, ByRef vOut As Variant)

Dim i As Long, arrayIndex1 As Long

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i, lInd) <> False Then 'exclude values "FALSE" from listing
            If lInd = UBound(arr, 2) Then
                For arrayIndex1 = LBound(vOut, 2) To UBound(vOut, 2)
                    vOut(outCnt, arrayIndex1) = Split(Mid$(s, 2) & "," & arr(i, lInd), ",")(arrayIndex1 - 1)
                Next arrayIndex1
                If outCnt = 1000000 Then Exit Sub
                outCnt = outCnt + 1
            Else
                vOut(outCnt, lInd) = arr(i, lInd)
                Arrangements arr, s & "," & arr(i, lInd), lInd + 1, outCnt, vOut
            End If
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Edit:

I already found first improvement. Instead of splitting the same string on each arrayIndex1 iteration, I do the splitting outside of the loop and assign it to array. Execution time is now 18 seconds.

```
Dim outVals () as string
```

...

```
outVals = Split(Mid$(s, 2) & "," & arr(i, lInd), ",")

For arrayIndex1 = LBound(vOut, 2) To UBound(vOut, 2)
    vOut(outCnt, arrayIndex1) = outVals(arrayIndex1 - 1)
Next arrayIndex1
```

Edit 2:

Combinations input and output layout:

[image: Combinations input and output layout:]

Comment: `lastRow` is not used, I would `Redim Preserve vOut` to fit the data.  I don't see the point in partially clearing the old list.   Please provide some sample data and a screenshot of the desired output (only 10 rows or so).

Comment: Good catch with lastRow, initially combination columns had header and I was detecting last row, then cleared data from row 2 to last row. I'm not a big fan of `Redim Preserve`, it requires transposing array and transposing it back, I have a custom procedure to overcome 65k rows limit, but I still find pasting too big array to range which fits desired amount of rows more straightforward. I've added screenshot of input and output data.

Comment: Aww..your are correct.  Using Value2 will give you a small boost in speed using your dataset and a most significant boost working with dates.

Answer (score 1):

I continually get `Subscript Out of Range` at

> ```
> vOut(outCnt, arrayIndex1) = Split(Mid$(s, 2) & "," & arr(i, lInd), ",")(arrayIndex1 - 1)
> ```

#### ByRef

> ```
> Sub Arrangements(ByRef arr, ByVal s As String, ByVal lInd As Long, ByRef outCnt As Long, ByRef vOut As Variant)
>
> Arrangements arr, s & "," & arr(i, lInd), lInd + 1, outCnt, vOut
> ```

Why are you passing all these arguments `ByRef`? Especially because you're calling the procedure from within the procedure. By definition the `arr` passed ByVal will always persist as will the `outCnt`. The `vOut` is being passed back as well, so it doesn't need to be `ByRef`.

Do you see what I mean? If you had this -

```
Sub main()
    Dim i As Long
    i = 1
    adding i
End Sub
Sub adding(ByVal i As Long)
    If i > 0 Then i = i + 1
    adding i
End Sub
```

The `i` would increase every time it's passed back. What `ByRef` would be used for is making changes to something that *isn't* passed back.

That being said, why are you calling your procedure from within your procedure anyway?

> ```
> Sub Arrangements(ByRef arr, ByVal s As String, ByVal lInd As Long, ByRef outCnt As Long, ByRef vOut As Variant)
> For
>   If
>     If lInd = UBound(arr, 2) Then
>    Else
>        vOut(outCnt, lInd) = arr(i, lInd)
>        Arrangements arr, s & "," & arr(i, lInd), lInd + 1, outCnt, vOut
> End If
> ```

Seems to me if your second `If` isn't true, maybe you need to go to the next `For`? Or does it need to re-perform the entire process again?

Maybe I'm having trouble understanding it. I have no idea what `lInd` is.

#### Variables

***Give your variables meaningful names***. This makes following the code easier and it also makes future you happy that you can take a look and know what is happening without tracing the entire procedure.

1. `arr` - tell me of what. e.g. `arrayOfCombinations()`
2. `outCnt` = it's a count of what and where is it going out?
3. `vOut` - once again, what is this?
4. `s` -?
5. `arrayIndex1` - why is this #1? Is there a second one? Try to never put numerical digits in a variable's name
6. `lInd` - this is created as a `ByVal` argument and then sent back to itself as its own value. I - what?!

I'm not being mean, but how would I ever be able to figure out what `lInd` is if it's never truly defined and has a name that doesn't tell me much. That's very poor logic (of the procedure, not you).

#### Magic numbers

I see the number `1,000,000` twice. What is it? The number of combinations?

```
Const TOTAL_COMBINATIONS as Long = 1000000
```

Or name it whatever it is.